# React Native - How to hide other items in array when onPress one item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm displaying an array of items (`Circle` components) in my view, 
[image]

**but I'm not sure how to hide all the others when I click one (onPress is set up to zoom in and give more info cards about that one Circle I click).**

[image]

Here is my RN code .. any ideas?

```
class Circle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { opened: false};
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }

  onPress() {
    this.props.onPress();
    if (this.props.noAnimation) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.state.opened) {
      this.refs.nextEpisode.fadeOutLeft();
      this.refs.description.fadeOutDownBig();
      return  this.setState({opened: false, windowPos: null});
    }
    this.refs.container.measureInWindow((x, y) => {
      this.refs.nextEpisode.slideInLeft();
      setTimeout(() => this.refs.description.fadeInUpBig(), 400);
      this.setState({
        opened: true,
        windowPos: { x, y },
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.props.data;
    const { opened } = this.state;
    const styles2 = getStyles(opened, (this.props.index % 2 === 0));

    const containerPos = this.state.windowPos ? {
      top: - this.state.windowPos.y + 64
    } : {};

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPress}>
        <View style={[styles2.container, containerPos]} ref="container" >
          <TvShowImage tvShow={data} style={styles2.image} noShadow={opened} openStatus={opened}/>
          <View style={styles2.title}>
            <Title
              tvShow={data}
              onPress={this.onPress}
              noShadow={opened}
            />
            <Animatable.View
              style={styles2.animatableNextEpisode}
              duration={800}
              ref="nextEpisode"
            >
              <NextEpisode tvShow={data}/>
            </Animatable.View>
          </View>
          <Animatable.View
            style={styles2.description}
            duration={800}
            ref="description"
            delay={400}
          >
            <Text style={styles2.descriptionText}>{data.item_description}</Text>
          </Animatable.View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
Circle.defaultProps = {
  index: 0,
  onPress: () => {}
};
```

(Please ignore that some of variable names are tv-show related when the photos are food-related, haven't had time to fix yet).

FYI the parent component that maps the array of `Circle` components looks like this:

```
class Favorites extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      circleCount: 0
    };
    this.addCircle = this.addCircle.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.props.screenProps.appstate.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addCircle();
      }, (i*100));
    }
  }
  addCircle = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({circleCount: prevState.circleCount + 1}));
  }

  render() {
    var favoritesList = this.props.screenProps.appstate;

    var circles = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.circleCount; i++) {

      circles.push(
          <Circle key={favoritesList[i].url} style={styles.testcontainer} data={favoritesList[i]}>

          </Circle>
      );
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: '#fff9f9'}}>
          <View style={styles.favoritesMainView}>
            <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
              {circles}
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you like to use the animation, you can't remove the rest of circle out of the list. Add a isShown property to circle, when the circle does not show, set the height to 0. Bubble up the onPress event, so when one circle is pressed, set the rest isShown to false. BTW this will not work if you circles don't have key props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head (if I'm understanding what you want) there could be few solutions.

You may need to track the "selected" circle and style the components based on that. For instance you could style the ones not selected by using `{height: 0}` or `{opacity: 0}` if you still need the height of the elements.

To track I would try the following:

In Favorites state:

```
this.state = {
  circleCount: 0,
  selected: -1
};
```

And pass 3 new values to circle, the third is function to change the state of "selected":

```
<Circle
  key={favoritesList[i].url}
  style={styles.testcontainer}
  data={favoritesList[i]}
  index={i}
  selected={this.state.selected}
  onClick={(index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, selected: index }
    });
  }}
/>
```

In Circle we use pass the index that was pressed back up to Favorites using the method we passed down:

```
onPress() {
  this.props.onClick(this.props.index);
  ...
```

In Circle's render method we create an opacity style to hide any elements not currently selected (but only if there is one selected - meaning that if it is -1 then none are selected and no opacity should be applied to any Circle:

```
render() {
  const { selected, index } = this.props;
  let opacityStyle = {};
  if(selected !== -1) {
    if(selected !== index) {
      opacityStyle = { opacity: 0 }
    }
  }
```

Last step is to apply the style (either an empty object, or opacity: 0):

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPress}>
    <View style={[styles2.container, containerPos, opacityStyle]} ref="container" >
```

I am not sure where you are closing or zooming out. Just when you close or zoom out of a circle you just need to call `this.props.onClick(-1)` to effectively deselect the circle. This will mean no other circles will have the opacity applied.

---

One thing you may need to do to ensure "selected" is not removed, is change your setState() method in Favorites:

```
addCircle = () => {
this.setState(prevState => {
    return { ...prevState, circleCount: prevState.circleCount + 1 };
  }
)}
```

In this version we are only changing circleCount and leaving any other properties that prevState has - in this case "selected" remains unchanged.

Comment: hey @adam_ thanks for the response -- reads like a book! really fantastic. I copied each of your steps by the letter and actually, maybe there's one thing that is flipped around? because i'm actually seeing perhaps the opposite effect--- when I click on 1 item in the listview, that one item is the only thing that disappears (instead of zooming out to show all the info and extra components about it), and all the other items remain. it's kind of the opposite of the intended effect haha. any idea?

Comment: hey! so looks like changing `if(selected === index)` to `if(selected !== index)` and inserting `this.props.onClick(-1);`under the `if (this.state.opened) { }` function of the `Circle` component does the trick! does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah, looks like I made a small mistake with the logic. Good pickup! Glad you got something out of all my writing!